# Angular: Is it a good practice to have a loooong list of typeahead results or better to do many requests?

Tags: javascript, angular, api

so I have more of a dilemma...

I am trying to do a simple user-name change form, where a user can change his user name... but obviously this has to be unique... now..

the usernames itself are not sensitive information, so if I expose the list of all to the user is not a big deal (I will have a simple scramble just in case)...

so the dilemma is: Should I pre-fetch all possible usernames (max there will be couple of thousands) and validate against that array each keystroke...

or do I do a (debounced) api call for every keystroke (and cache the results)?

if you think the first option is OK (given the security is not an issue), how many is too many? I would do it for up to 100, no question... but what if there are 5k, is this still OK?

or should I just do a regular one and check availability only on form submit? and return just true/false depending on availability?

Comment: Why not just do onBlur and return true or false instead of per key press.

Comment: I don't get it - if exposing the usernames is fine, then why have a scramble? And what are you going to scramble anyway?

Comment: Do a debounced api call.  The biggest danger you have with pulling the list is the data going stale.  This can then cause serious concurrency issues.

Comment: A debounced api call (maybe 500 ms timeout before making the api call). You can cancel any current call in progress.

Comment: @nurdyguy: darn it... that is a really good point.. so debounced it is... put it as an answer please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to pull a long list and then run it from local memory. The reason is that it can easily become stale which then causes significant concurrency issues.  If you *know* the data won't change very often (like, no more than once a day) then you can get away with it but even then, not a great idea.  For this reason, a debounced api call is very much preferred.  I usually debounce this kind of thing at somewhere between 500-1000ms with a forced call (ignoring the timer) on events like 'enter' or blur.

Side notes:

1. You shouldn't be returning what usernames are *taken* but rather just a bool for "isAvailable" when there is no match.
2. Even with this methodology there is still a concurrency issue which can occur between the last validating fetch and the time the user hits enter.  The uniqueness should be enforced on the db and the code should surround the db call with a try/catch in case of the concurrency hit.  It is an annoying thing, race conditions always are.